# How I can get all items of table with Selenium (Python3 )?

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, python-3.7

I want to get information from table at the page https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/wolves-newcastle-utd-nNNqedbR/ .

This is a table, which automatically change her items(mb with js, ajax).
[image]

If i write following code, I get error *'HtmlElement' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'*

```
url = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/wolves-newcastle-utd-nNNqedbR/'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)

html = lxml.html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
tbody = html.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[1]/table/tbody')
trows = tbody.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lxml is (presumably) the [lxml](https://lxml.de) library, so your `html` object is an instance of it. As the exception says - it does not have `find_element_by_xpath()` and tag_name methods, those are in the selenium library.

So instead of working with the `html` object, work with `driver`:

```
tbody = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[1]/table/tbody')
trows = tbody.find_element_by_tag_name("tr")
```

Comment: On the output I get list of rows: _[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8163e1ec932463898816cc51e60e22cc", element="0.36469099230520374-2")>, ..._ This is not exactly what I expected. Can I continue to work with this to extract the contents of the cells?

Comment: You're printing `tbody` and `trows`? They are webelement objects, thus you see that; if you want to get the element's text, try with `tbody.text`.